# How to remove one of the group inputs

Tags: node-editor, groups

I'm using Blender 2.74 and trying to follow an online video tutorial on creating "sun" (presenter is using version 2.63). The problem I'm facing is that the presenter just selected a few nodes in the Nodes Editor and pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd> to group those nodes. Then he pressed <kbd>TAB</kbd> to edit the group and remove some of the input sockets of the **GroupInput** node by clicking the cross button in front of those sockets. Now I do not see these cross buttons in my version of Blender. I tried using Properties window too (<kbd>N</kbd> key) but that also doesn't allow removing (although it does allow adding, renaming and reordering). Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Figured it out at last. Select the group input node and press <kbd>N</kbd> key to bring up Properties window. You can then use the cross button next to the node label that appears immediately below the inputs and outputs list. Here's a snapshot:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

In the Shader Editor view, select the group node and enter Edit Group mode. Open the right side panel with <kbd>N</kbd>

In the first tab, called Group, you can access the inputs. Highlight the one you want to delete and press the `-` button to remove it.

Answer (score 0):

For Blender 2.92:
I pressed N and it brought the options and there's the Node Wrangler (you'll have to enable this plugin. Then press the node of the interest - in my example it's Material Output, and then press Frame Selected. And it's out. However I didn't find how to remove that frame about it, but that's good enough for me.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In Blender 3.2 I found this not far away: press <kbd>N</kbd> and choose **Group** instead of **View**.